# How do I lock out all PC activity depending on time?

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls, lock

I'd like to enforce a curfew, say 11 PM, and stop a kid from using the PC after that, locking the user out of all activity unless a password is given until morning.

Is there some way to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: Did you check the parental controls in Windows 7?

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 are you using? (Go to Start menu > Right Click Computer > Select Properties ... It's in the right panel right under 'Windows Edition'.

Answer (score 2):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/parental-controls

Use Windows Parental Controls, located in Control Panel.